# How to include jquery ui (with styles) in ruby on rails correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I`ve seen some information here but it looks kind of not audible for me.

I included `//= require jquery-ui` in application.js

Where should i place directory with styles and how it should be called? Could you please provide step by step instruction.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply put your stylesheets and javascripts as follow

```
 directories path for javascript

     vendor -> assets -> javascript
```

and require file in application.js

```
         //= require jquery-ui
        //= require_self
       //= require_tree .         


      directories path for style sheets

     vendor -> assets -> stylesheets

       *=require style
       *= require_tree .
```

It will sure work for you